# Propel preSave() can't get records form database

Tags: php, orm, propel

I am building some webapp. I don't want the user to rewrite value in database if it already is there. I am trying to check this with preSave() behavior. Whenever i try to get the value from database i get the value the user just posted in with $_POST[]

```
public function preSave(\PropelPDO $con = null) {
    $obj = new UserQuery();
    //let's check if user has set the value
    $type = $obj->findOneById($this->getId())->getType();
    var_dump($type);// <-- here the value from database is always as user 
                    //have just been selected in form. The value in database 
                    //actually is NULL

    //if type in database have been saved then set the current type from database 
    if(!is_null($type))
        $this->setType($type);

    return true;
}
```

So my question is: Why the value from database is never NULL, but some TRUE or FALSE as user have picked in form? It should be NULL cause in that moment save() haven't been executed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you're getting the same object because of the [Propel instance pooling](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#propel-instance-pool). It just *caches* the previously fetched objects. So, you can try to disable instance pooling for the `preSave` method:

```
public function preSave(\PropelPDO $con = null) {
    \Propel::disableInstancePooling();
    // your code...
    \Propel::enableInstancePooling();
}
```